# How to pass response from service to component?

Tags: angular

I have this service:

```
Login (body): Observable<Login[]> {

        //let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
        var bodyString = 'email='+body.email +'&password='+body.password;

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

        return this.http.post('/logiranje', bodyString, options) // ...using post request
                         .map(response => {return response}) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error' )); //...errors if any
    }
```

I have component:

```
  submitLogin(values){

            var current = this;
      // Variable to hold a reference of addComment/updateComment
         let loginOperation:Observable<any>;
         loginOperation = this.loginService.Login(values);
         loginOperation.subscribe(
           (response) => { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
            function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
            function(){

               current.router.navigate(['/home']);
               console.log("the subscription is completed");


             }
        );

       }
```

What i want is to check :

```
if(response.isLoggedIn){
current.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

But i dont know how to pass value from service to component?
Any suggestion how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your you expect your response to be a JSON. You should then map it as below :

```
return this.http.post('/logiranje', bodyString, options)
  .map(response => { response.json() }) 
  .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error' ));
```

Since you already injected your service in your component you'll just have to assign the response to a variable :

```
data : any;

constructor(private loginService : LoginService) {}

myFunction(body){
    this.loginService.Login(body).subscribe(
      res => { this.data = res },
      err => { console.log(err) }
    );
}
```

Then you can use your `data` variable

```
if(this.data.isLoggedIn){
  current.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

Comment: when you use your code what does `console.log(response)` display ?
Did you define a `data` variable as I did in the first line ?

Comment: "Success ResponseResponse with status: 200 OK for URL: http://localhost:3000/logiranje"  login.component.js:38:68
the subscription is completed

Comment: So your response is not a JSON and thus `this.data.isLoggedIn` will be undefined.

Comment: I edit my code so that your response will be correctly mapped to json